# does sklearn rbm scale well with sparse high dimensional features

Tags: machine-learning, restricted-boltzmann-machine, scikit-learn

i am using scikit learn's RBM implementation. There are two problems:

1. The running time is O(d^2) where d is the number of features. This becomes a problem in using high dimensionality sparse features. Consider features that come from feature hashing for instance.
2. It only allows for binary visible features. Do I have to change the sklearn code to have non binary units or there is some trick that I am unaware of?

I am expecting RBMs with 4 features to have a better fit than a mixture of 2 gaussians (that has a similar number of parameters). Has anyone seen any experiments done on RBMs for unsupervised modeling other than pretraining?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Training time

RBM training time depends on several parameters, most importantly from a number of iterations, number of Gibbs sampling loops and a size of weight matrix. First 2 are easy to manipulate, while the last one depends is always $m \times n$, where $m$ is a number of visible and $n$ - number of hidden units. So actual time complexity of training RBM with respect to the number of features is $O(m \times n)$.

Unfortunately, there's not much you can do with it. Unlike input data, **weight matrix has to be dense** to be able to sample hidden units from visible ones and vise versa. You can play around with a number of hidden units, though, but don't expect RBM being training at the same speed as SVM or logistic regression, for example.

Note, that if your data has a notion of locality (e.g. nearby pixels on an image or words in a text), you can also try out **convolutional networks** which have much smaller weight matrices and often produce better results.

## Binary features

Yes, SciKit Learn includes only BernoulliRBM, which is RBM with binary units. However, it doesn't apply any constraints on input data. It turns out that **BernoulliRBM can handle real-valued data** (e.g. image data) **pretty successfully**, even though theoretical implications of such a hack are unclear.

If you are looking for strictly real-valued RBM and using something different than Python/SciKit Learn is an option for you, also take a look at [Boltzmann.jl](https://github.com/dfdx/Boltzmann.jl) - my implementation of RBM in Julia heavily based on sklearn's version, but also including Gaussian RBM. More time-consuming, but helpful alternative is to port GRBM back to SciKit Learn, which basically requires only rewriting a couple of methods for sampling.

## Usage of RBMs other than pretraining

RBMs are useful not only for pretraining in deep networks, but also for **representation learning** (feature extraction), **dimensionality reduction**, **probability distribution estimation** (and thus sampling) and many other tasks. I've successfully used them for retrieving facial expression "modes" from images of emotional faces and [analysis of last.fm data](http://www.slideshare.net/faithlessfriend/tone-deaf-finding-structure-in-lastfm-data). RBMs are quite popular in *recommendation systems* (e.g. see [paper by Salakhutdinov](http://www.machinelearning.org/proceedings/icml2007/papers/407.pdf) or another by [Netflix Prize winners](http://www.netflixprize.com/assets/GrandPrize2009_BPC_BellKor.pdf)), [*music retrieval*](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~juhan/pubs/jnam-ismir2012.pdf) and different applications of *natural language processing*.